# How to add an external (packaged) Service Fabric Service to Application Manifest

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We want to ingest bunch of external Service Fabric Services, which are packaged into Universal Packages.

To download these services, I had to use `vsts cli` - once they are downloaded I can see the `ServiceManifest.xml` and the `Code / Config` folders in the location that I've downloaded. I now want to add them as some kind of external services to my manifest.

How should I modify the `ApplicationManifest.xml` so these services are added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `<ServiceManifestImport>` node in `ApplicationManifest.xml` you should add references to each of the service you would like to have in your application.

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="ServicePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
  <ConfigOverrides />
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

Here is two important things to understand:

1. While in general one `ServiceManifest.xml` contains definition of single service from the design standpoint `ServiceManifest.xml` describes a so-called **service package**. This service package is the thing referenced inside `ApplicationManifest.xml`.
2. The value of `ServiceManifestName` attribute is the name of `ServiceManifest.xml`. `ServiceManifest.xml` name is defined inside it using `ServiceManifest/@Name`attribute. At the same time `ServiceManifestName` attribute defines name of directory relative to location of `ApplicationManifest.xml` where `ServiceManifest.xml`, `Code`, `Config` and other folders are located.

Here is a quick example

Imagine you assemble a package in `C:\MyPackage` directory and you want to use external service which has `Service1` name in `ServiceManifest.xml`.

1. The first thing you do is adding this service to `ApplicationManifest.xml`

   ```
   <ServiceManifestImport>
     <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Service1" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" /> 
     <ConfigOverrides />
   </ServiceManifestImport>
   ```
2. Now you copy  `ApplicationManifest.xml` to `C:\MyPackage` directory.
3. Then you create a `C:\MyPackage\Service1` directory and copy `ServiceManifest.xml`, `Code` and etc. to `C:\MyPackage\Service1`.
4. In order to make sure everything is alright you execute a PowerShell cmdlet `Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage C:\MyPackage`

Hope this helps.